# How can i subscribe to an Observables in a function

Tags: angular

I have a function in my angular app which is called when a user enters some data in text box to validate the data against an API. I got that working just fin except the call against the API is causing me issues. In my old code i used promises and that worked fine but i am trying to move to observable and that's causing me issues.

Here is the code for the service i am calling..

```
  validateUsername(username: string): Observable<IAPIResponse> {
    const requestUrl = `/user/validateUserName/${username}`;
    return this.httpservice.get<IAPIResponse>({
      endpoint: this.baseUrl + requestUrl,
      params: {}, })
      .pipe(
        map(result => result as IAPIResponse),
        tap(result => console.log(result.Data))
   );
```

and my function looks like this..

```
userNameAvail?: Observable<any>;

  validateUsername(event: any){

    console.log('New Username : ' + event.target.value);
    this.userNameAvail = this.userservice.validateUsername(event.target.value);
    console.log(this.userNameAvail);
  })
```

So my question is what am i missing to subscribe to that observable correctly and get access to the data in my function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private subscriptionValidateUserName : Subscription;      

 validate(event: any){

    console.log('New Username : ' + event.target.value);
    this.subscriptionValidateUserName = this.userservice.validateUsername(event.target.value).subscribe( data -> {
     console.log(data);
    });;
  })
```

After subscribing you can't hold an Observable.

What you can hold is a Subscription which is important to unsubscribe when you finish doing something if you don't want to be triggered later accidentally.
If you want to unsubscribe then just do `this.subscriptionValidateUserName.unsubscribe();`

Comment: When doing that i am back to using the subscribe which is deprecated. subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of a complete callback (deprecation). Also i can not assign my userNameAvail?: Observable<any> the the observable via subscribe because i get this error Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Comment: @SamS87 your second method had the same name with the first one. Changed it to validate it should work when you call now `this.validate('name')`

Answer (score 0):

observable never execute until you call subscibe.
but it is important to unsubscribe it.
Better solution to subscribe and unsubscribe to any rxjs observable is :
create BaseComponent that inside it declare varibale _destory with type subject.
and in ngOnDestroy() call next.
after that inherit any component from this BaseComponent.
with this concept you feel easy to unsubscribe observable.

```
@Directive()
export class BaseComponent implements OnDestory{
   private _destroy=new Subject();
   ngOnDestroy(){
     this._destroy.next();
   }
}

export class SomeComponent extends BaseComponent{
  validateUsername(event: any){   
 this.userservice.validateUsername(event.target.value)
 .pipe(
       takeUntil(this._destroy))
 .subscribe(result=>
    console.log(result);
  })
}
```